# Spring MVC view controller redirection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it possible not to redirect to a view without query parameters? I have a `login` view and I want to redirect to `login?error` url in browser when login fails. I have my own `AuthenticationFailureHandler`:

```
public class SomeCustomHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
  private final SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login?error");

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    authenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
  }
}
```

configured in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
      .requestMatchers()
      .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
    .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .failureHandler(new SomeCustomHandler())
    .permitAll();
}
```

But when login fails, returned `login?error` is redirected in user to `login` ignoring `?error` parameter.

[image]

Here is my MvcWebConfigurer:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addViewController("/login/**").setViewName("login"); 
}
```

Comment: please change `registry.addViewController("/login/**").setViewName("login");` to `registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");` and try again and let me know

Comment: Unfortunately it's still the same.

Comment: try to add a view for login?error `registry.addViewController("/login?error").setViewName("errorpage")`

Comment: Also add `.antMatchers("/login?error"").permitAll()` in `configure(HttpSecurity http)`

Comment: I would like to have a single `/login` page, because I'll have multiple error reasons, e.g. `?error=bad-credentials` or `?error=locked-account` and there will be a single `<div>` on `/login` page with error message based on error type passed as query parameter. Creating separate `errorpage` would cause creating new page for each error type, and the only difference between those pages would be the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to do something like that:

```
public class SomeCustomHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    private final SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login?error");

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(request.getPathInfo().startsWith("/login") && !request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
            authenticationFailureHandler.setUseForward(true);
        }
        authenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```